# Explanation about slicing operation in lists (python)

Tags: python, list, slice, assignment-operator

I wanted to understand the behavior displayed in the code. I was using the python interactive session to check the slicing operation.

I am not able to understand why it gives the below shown output .  I am using version 3.1.2

```
testList =[1,2,3,4,5]

testList[3:1] = ["adds"]

[1, 2, 3, 'adds', 4, 5]
```

If I type `testList[3:1]` , it just displays an empty list but if I assign a list to it , it gets added.

How and why does it get added to the list

Answer (score 0):

It's a quirk of the language. `testList[3:1]` will not return anything since the start index (3) is greater than the end index (1). The operation `testList[4:5] = [1,2,3,4,5]` will replace item 4 in testList and inserts the rest of the items after it.

So, in your example `testList[3:1] = ["addr"]`, it moves to index 3, sees that it won't replace anything, and inserts "addr".

Answer (score 0):

```
a[start:stop]
```

"stop" value represents the first value that is not in the selected slice.

```
testList[3:1]
```

Selects a number of elements that is the difference between "stop" and "start", thus it gives you an empty list.